# How to correctly choose work_group_size?

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication with OpenCl.
A is 1000x1000, B is 1000x1000, so my C=AxB is 1000x1000 also.
My local_size is, for example, 14.

```
size_t local_item_size[2]  = { local_size, local_size };
```

I've read that the work group size it's the size of my problem. C has 2 dimensions, so I would try to set

```
size_t work_group_size[2] = 
    { N, N };

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(dev.queue, kernel, 2, 0, 
                             global_item_size, work_group_size,
                             0, NULL, &event);
```

But I get a `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`. How can I correctly choose global_item_size My pc's max work group size is 1024. Does it mean that I can't work with bigger matrices?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local size must be an exact divisor of global size.

1000x1000 is exactly divisible by 10x10 or 20x5 and similar

If you insist on local size 14, you should pad your whole array to have something like 1400x1400 so it works but not exactly at the padded patches. This has wasted cycles but at least compatible for any sizes until(and including) 1400x1400.

If your device has max local size of 1024, then it can handle 32x32 local size. Or 1024 in 1-D.